# How to Inhibits React Big Calendar event to drag on previous date

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, drag-and-drop, react-big-calendar

How to inhibits user to create or drag any event before today's date, i'm using [this library](https://jquense.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add custom logic to your `onEventDrop` or `onDropFromOutside` methods to prevent dropping an event on anything you might consider a disabled date.